# Change the title of UIButton in TableViewCell when tapped using let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Here I've retrieved the data from Parse and I'm showing that data in `tableViewCell`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("users", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! userListTableViewCell

    let userData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    // Usernames and gender..

    myCell.fullName.text = userData.objectForKey("fullName") as! String!
    myCell.genderLabel.text = userData.objectForKey("gender") as! String!

    // Profile pictures..

    let profilePics = userData.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile
    profilePics.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.dp.image = downloadedImage
        }

    }

    myCell.followButtton.addTarget(self, action: "followButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)



    return myCell
}
```

now i've applied `UIButton` in `UITableViewCell` successfully , i am getting the co-ordinates well this way :

```
// IBActions..


func followButtonTapped(sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
    if indexPath != nil {



        println(indexPath)


    }
}
```

now when the user taps on any button i want to change the title of that button. Thanks for your time ..And sorry if it's a basic question I'm asking, i am a beginner .

This is what I am getting when the button is being tapped..

`<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000010016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}`

can i use this?

```
func followButtonTapped(sender:AnyObject) {
let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
if indexPath != nil {

    sender.setTitle("title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    println(indexPath)


   }
}
```

.... I'm open to any type of answer..any better way would also be accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func followButtonTapped(sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
    if indexPath != nil {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowatindexPath(indexPath){
       cell.followButton.setTitle("input title here")
}


        println(indexPath)


    }
}
```

Comment: `cellForRowatindexPath(indexPath)` this method can't be called here..

i figured it out. 

`if indexPath != nil {
            
        
            sender.setTitle("unfollow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            
         //   println(indexPath!)
            
           
            
        }`

Comment: is this fine to do rite?